# DJANGO: send_mail is not throwing errors or exceptions

Tags: django, django-email

I want to send smtp emails. But it is not working and I do not know how to debug this problem.

In my settings.py I set a complete wrong port:

```
EMAIL_PORT = 3
```

In the Django shell I run this script without getting an error. send_mail is just returning 1 after execution.

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail(
    'Test Email',
    'That is an test.',
    'test@test.com',
    ['test@gmail.com'],
    fail_silently=False,
)
```

I also have configured an error logger, which should log everything. But it is also not appearing anything in my logfile:

```
...
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
...
```

Is this the default behavior? I guess no? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is your email backend?

Comment: 'django.core.mail.backends.filebased.EmailBackend'

Thank you! Not sure where this is coming from. But now it is clear where the problem is coming from